# Dell Precision T3500 Intel Rapid Storange Technology shows no Acceleration option?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, raid

I have a Dell Precision T3500 with a 2TB HDD with my OS installed and a brand new 128GB SSD which is not formatted. The SATA mode is set to RAID in BIOS and the latest version of the Intel Rapid Storage Technology drivers and software is installed.

When i go into the IRTS application there is no button for me to set up acceleration on the SSD.

I've done a bit of Googling before posting, here's the things i've already tried:

Creating a simple volume partition on the SSD and formatting it and running IRTS.
Deleting that partition and running IRTS.
Changing to AHCI SATA mode booting and then changing back to RAID.
Configuring it in bootup by pressing CTRL-I the acceleration option (5) is greyed out.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Any help would be really appreciated thanks!

Comment: The T3500 is based on the Intel X58 chipset . . . Intel's Smart Response stuff wasn't supported till the Z68 . . .

Comment: Thanks i had just assumed that if it supported Intel Rapid Storage that it would support acceleration, cheers anyway!